# Entity Framework 6 updates all records with data of the one getting updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement entity framework 6 in my application, but I have a problem performing updates on the records.

If I have 2 records in the database, lets say:

| Id | Name | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason | Momoa |
| 2 | Aqua | Man |

Then I alter the one with id 1 from "Jason" to "Water" and call the `UpdatePerson` function, with a new `Person` object that has the same primary key.

The result will be:

| Id | Name | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water | Momoa |
| 2 | Water | Momoa |

WHY should that be the result?? I was already looking around for a solution but could not find any clue. Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

As far as I understood the disconnected datacontext I used, can simply update a record with the knowledge of the primary key.

For reference the page for [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#attaching-an-existing-but-modified-entity-to-the-context)

My code looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private int _id = -1;
    private string _name;
    private string _lastname;

    public int PersonId { get => _id; set => _id = value; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get => _lastname; set => _lastname = value; }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1() : base("name=entity_test") { }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }     
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        using (Model1 context = new Model1())
        {
            var list = context.People.AsNoTracking().ToList();
            if (list == null)
                return null;
            return new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);
        }
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        using (Model1 context = new Model1())
        {
            context.People.Add(person);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        using (Model1 context = new Model1())
        {
            context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Tables were not displayed nicely.

**EDIT 2**

Here the rest of the code and the output of `context.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);`

Output:

```
`Person_Update`


-- PersonId: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Name: 'Water' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 5)

-- Lastname: 'Momoa' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 5)

-- Executing at 29.10.2021 16:46:05 +02:00

-- Completed in 198 ms with result: 2
```

Code:

```
public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonModel model = new PersonModel();

        if (DataContext is ViewModel vm)
        {
            vm.AddModifyPerson();
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : NotifyBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
        model = new PersonModel();

        using (var db = new Model1())
        {
            // create if not exists
            if (db.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            People = model.GetPeople();
        }
    }

    private PersonModel model;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    private Person currentPerson = new Person();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get => people; set => SetProperty(ref people, value); }
    public Person CurrentPerson { get => currentPerson; set => SetProperty(ref currentPerson, value); }

    public void AddModifyPerson()
    {
        if (CurrentPerson.PersonId == -1)
        {
            model.AddPerson(CurrentPerson);
        }
        else
        {
            model.UpdatePerson(
                new Person()
                {
                    PersonId = CurrentPerson.PersonId,
                    Lastname = CurrentPerson.Lastname,
                    Name = CurrentPerson.Name,
                });
        }
        People = model.GetPeople();
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

Code for from miniprofiler

```
    public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        var profiler = MiniProfiler.StartNew("My Profiler");
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Update_Sql"))
        {
            using (Model1 context = new Model1())
            {
                context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(MiniProfiler.Current.RenderPlainText());
    }
```

**EDIT 4**

output of an update call from mysql.general_log

| command_type | argument |
| --- | --- |
| Init DB | entity_test |
| Query | SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ |
| Query | BEGIN |
| Query | CALL Person_Update(1, 'Jason1', 'Momoa') |
| Query | COMMIT |

It does look like the update procedure is not performing the where clause. If I run `call Person_Update_Custom(1, 'test','tes')` in the workbench all rows are updated. Here is the stored procedure:

```sql
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Person_Update`(IN PersonId int,IN Name varchar(255) ,IN Lastname longtext)
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE `People` SET `Name`=Name, `Lastname`=Lastname WHERE `PersonId` = PersonId;
     END
```

Comment: Hi there, could you provide some code showing how you are creating the new element and performing the update operation? from what you are describing it looks like you are performing an update without the Id, you can also try to use tools like https://miniprofiler.com/ to check on the SQL queries being sent to the DB, that might give you insight into the issue

Comment: @ArmandoBracho I've added the rest of the code. After I figure out how to use miniprofile I will add that too.
Meanwhile, I could check the sql query with the command 
`context.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);`
as the result is that 2 records got alterd. (details in question Edit 2)

Comment: @ArmandoBracho The output of the miniprofiler is `My Profiler 0ms >> Update_Sql 305,5ms (sql = 41,8ms in 9 cmds)` (Code in Edit3)

Comment: The error seems to be in the stored procedure.

Comment: I would look at setting up an SQL profiler on the database to capture the actual SQL being sent. I cannot spot anything obvious, but I am very wary about the number of references to a *Person* being tracked between People and CurrentPerson. Any call to update a person from a client should include a PersonId. Normally for an update I would fetch the Person from the DB, assert the row version hasn't changed (another update since this client read it) then copy across the fields that are allowed to be updated. Using detached entities allows clients to modify anything and everything on the entity.

Comment: @GertArnold It really looks like that. When I call the procedure directly from the workbench it will update all rows too. I have added the procedure to *Edit 4*. For me the procedure looks fine...

Comment: @StevePy In the profiler everything seems normal. Maybe I need to set up a connected database context, instead of a detached one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after seeing in the miniprofiler (thanks Armando Bracho) and the mysql log (thanks Steve Py) that there was always one single sql query and Gert Arnold pointing out the procedure could be failing, I focused on the procedure.

It looks like, the procedure mixes the `PersonId` column name with the `PersonId` variable defined in the `CREATE PROCEDURE`-header.

So I've added some code to define the update procedure parameters by hand.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Update(pp => pp.HasName("Person_Update").Parameter(pm => pm.Name, "db_Name").Parameter(pm => pm.Lastname, "db_Lastname").Parameter(pm => pm.PersonId, "db_PersonId")));
}
```

which changes the stored procedure to:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Person_Update`(IN db_PersonId int,IN db_Name varchar(255) ,IN db_Lastname longtext)
BEGIN 
UPDATE `People` SET `Name`=db_Name, `Lastname`=db_Lastname WHERE `PersonId` = db_PersonId;
 END
```

and this finally works! One row affected.

**EDIT**

It's enough to change the `MapToStoredProcedures` to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Update(pp => pp.HasName("Person_Update").Parameter(pm => pm.PersonId, "db_PersonId")));
```

this ways one does not have define it for all properties.